# Безопасный доступ к одной базе данных с нескольких DBContext (Entity Framework C#)

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

возник один вопрос при разработке своего приложения. В чем суть? Была задача создать общее приложение, в котором несколько модулей (отдельные исполняемые файлы). Причины такого решения объяснять не буду, но главное, что так требовалось. В данный момент возникла потребность работы с базами данных, я работаю с DBContext (Entity Framework C#) и все хорошо если я подключаюсь к базе данных с одного модуля. Но через некоторое время возникла потребность также обращаться к базе данных с нескольких модулей одновременно. Как я знаю в Entity Framework подгрузка изменений с базы данных идет не постоянно, поэтому при изменении базы данных (какой-либо строки) в одном модуле, в других изменения не отобразятся. В этом и состоит проблема.

Можно ли как-то сделать синхронизацию, может заново подгружать при обновлении? Пока в голове только одна мысль: сделать отдельный модуль, который единственный будет иметь доступ к базе данных, и к этому модулю обращаться с других по надобности. Но это займет довольно много времени. Поэтому не знаю что делать. Если есть эксперты - с радостью выслушаю предложения )

PS: На данный момент "общение" между другими модулями осуществляется по веб-сокету, возможно его также можно использовать для решения

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир (микро)сервисов! (злорадный смех). / Вообще, если БД всего одна, то разумно сделать отдельный модуль (слой доступа) к ней. А вот если используется несколько БД, тогда делаем разные контексты. / На тему синхронизации состояний написано множество статей и толстых книг. Способы решения разные. Либо постоянно опрашиваем БД. Либо шлём сообщения из сервиса в сервис по шине...

Comment: Здравствуйте, доступ нужен к одно бд и в некоторых сценариях даже к одной таблице, поэтому думаю писать отдельный модуль, но тогда меня тревожить эффективность, если будет запрос к одной таблице от нескольких модулей других, то придется каждому ждать, пока не закончит другой. И при большом количестве запросов в минуту/секунду это будет сильно заметно

Comment: Нет, модули не будут ждать друг друга.

Comment: Почему модули будут ждать друг друга?

Comment: Представим ситуацию, мне надо получить пользователя, изменить ему переменную и сохранить обратно, это действие первого модуля, в то же время поступает почти аналогичная задача с другого модуля. Одновременное обращение к DBContext невозможно, будет выдавать исключение, собственно надо блокировать или использовать SemaphoreSlim что бы не было несостыковки. В таком случае пока не выполнится задача с одним и тем же пользователем одного модуля, второй не сможет приступить к работе и будет ждать

Comment: Также при работе с EF я не могу понять как мне передавать объекты классов со связями от модуля к модулю, через JSON?

Comment: Также добавлю что другие модули между собой работают на локальном веб-сокете, возможно тут можно и его использовать

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Можете подсказать как лучше реализовать в моем случае?

Comment: Не надо одновременно обращаться к одному DbContext. На каждый запрос создаётся свой экземпляр - всё, проблемы нет. / Передавать объекты (хоть со связями, хоть без) стандартно: сериализуете в любой удобный формат (например, JSON).

Comment: Если вы будете сохранять данные при их изменении, а при отображении читать из базы, то не вижу никаких проблем работы нескольких клиентов с базой. Без более подробного описания сценария обсуждение бессмысленно. Если вы хотите всё подряд кэшировать, то да, у вас будут проблемы с актуальностью кэша. А если вы ничего сами не кэшируете, а работаете всё время с базой правильным образом, то не нужно ничего городить дополнительного

Comment: Понял, благодарю. Вариант создавать каждый раз отдельные DbContext видел что затратный, тем более если много разных свой. Оказывается это не сильно влияет. Благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С решением помогли в комментариях. Было несколько вариантов:

- создать отдельный микросервис который будет один принимать запросы и давать на них ответы. Данный вариант довольно затратный, это почти как писать отдельный `API`, на это времени нет.
- синхронизировать все `DBContext`'ы. Тут тоже довольно сложно, прочитал несколько статей про синхронизацию, были варианты сделать все на основе организации трехэлементных очередей, но тут также надо потратить время и силы что бы все организовать.
- последний вариант, это каждый раз при запросе создавать новый `DBContext`. В таком случае, данные будут подгружаться с базы данных а не с локального кэша, соответсвенно всегда будут актуальными. При записи также, делаем все изменения которые надо, далее `SaveChanges()` и данные сразу сохраняются в базу данных.

Последний вариант видел давно, но многие говорили что создавать каждый раз новый контекст это слишком затратно будет для памяти программы. Однако я попробовал сделать после совета @AlexanderPetrov, проверил по времени обработки запроса, и по итогу разница совсем незначительная, при этом и данные всегда актульные.

Благодарю за помощь @AlexanderPetrov и @CrazyElf

Comment: Над кэшированием и прочими оптимизациями там же на многих уровнях люди думают. И SQL сам результаты запросов кэширует (и следит за актуальностью кеша) и на уровне фреймворка пул коннекшенов наверняка держится, поэтому изобретение велосипедов давно не актуально. И это не только в `EF`, а практически везде оптимальный стиль сейчас это открыть коннекшен, что-то сделать и закрыть коннекшен. Так и согласованность данных поддерживается на уровне БД и скорость получения данных не страдает.

Comment: Кстати, если вы быстро сохраняете результаты работы и не держите коннекшен, то как-раз это позволяет тратить меньше памяти. Когда вы долго держите контекст, то контекст должен отслеживать всё, что вы прочитали, не изменилось ли оно (если не использовалось `AsNoTracking` при чтении) и держать это в памяти. Вот это вот тратит и память и ресурсы.

Comment: Да, поэтому и принял такое решение, спасибо за помощь )